# I know scipy curve_fit can do better

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm using python/numpy/scipy to implement this algorithm for aligning two digital elevation models (DEMs) based on terrain aspect and slope:

"Co-registration and bias corrections of satellite elevation data sets for quantifying glacier thickness change", C. Nuth and A. Kääb, [doi:10.5194/tc-5-271-2011](http://dx.doi.org/10.5194/tc-5-271-2011)

I have things a framework set up, but the quality of the fit provided by scipy.optimize.curve_fit is poor.

```
def f(x, a, b, c):
    y = a * numpy.cos(numpy.deg2rad(b-x)) + c
    return y

def compute_offset(dh, slope, aspect):
    import scipy.optimize as optimization

    idx = random.sample(range(dh.compressed().size), 10000)
    xdata = numpy.array(aspect.compressed()[idx], float)
    ydata = numpy.array((dh/numpy.tan(numpy.deg2rad(slope))).compressed()[idx], float)

    #Generate synthetic data to test curve_fit
    #xdata = numpy.arange(0,360,0.01)
    #ydata = f(xdata, 20.0, 130.0, -3.0) + 20*numpy.random.normal(size=len(xdata))

    print xdata
    print ydata

    x0 = numpy.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])

    fit = optimization.curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, x0)[0]
    #optimization.leastsq(f, x0[:], args=(xdata, ydata))
    genplot(xdata, ydata, fit)
    return fit

def genplot(x, y, fit):
    a = (numpy.arange(0,360))
    f_a = f(a, fit[0], fit[1], fit[2])
    idx = random.sample(range(x.size), 10000)
    plt.figure()
    plt.xlabel('Aspect (deg)')
    plt.ylabel('dh/tan(slope) (m)')
    plt.plot(x[idx], y[idx], 'r.')
    plt.axhline(color='k')
    plt.plot(a, f_a, 'b')
    plt.ylim(-80,80)
    plt.show()

#Input DEMs
dem1_fn = sys.argv[1]
dem2_fn = sys.argv[2]

dem1_ds = gdal.Open(dem1_fn, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
dem2_ds = gdal.Open(dem2_fn, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)

#Extract band 1 from each dataset as masked array using internal nodata value
dem1 = getperc_new.gdal_getma(dem1_ds, 1)
dem2 = getperc_new.gdal_getma(dem2_ds, 1)

#Produce slope and aspect maps using gdaldem and load into masked arrays
dem1_slope = gdaldem_slope(dem1_fn)
dem1_aspect = gdaldem_aspect(dem1_fn)

#Compute common mask and apply to all products
common_mask = dem1.mask + dem2.mask + dem1_slope.mask + dem1_aspect.mask

diff_euler = numpy.ma.array(dem2-dem1, mask=common_mask)
dem1_slope.__setmask__(common_mask)
dem1_aspect.__setmask__(common_mask)

#Compute relationship between elevation difference, slope and aspect
fit = compute_offset(diff_euler, dem1_slope, dem1_aspect)
print fit
```

Here is the fit for my data, which initially consists of ~2 million points, but I've randomly sampled for testing/plotting purposes:

[ -14.9639559   216.01093596  -41.96806735]

[image: plot_one]

There is plenty of data there for a good fit, but the result from curve_fit is poor.  When I run   with synthetic data, I get a nice fit:

original input parameters [20.0, 130.0, -3.0]

result from curve_fit [-19.66719631 -49.6673076   -3.12198723]

[image: plot_two]

Not sure if this has something to do with using masked arrays, a limitation of curve_fit, or if I'm just overlooking something simple.  Thanks for any suggestions.

==========================

Edit 9/4/13 16:30 PDT

As suggested by @Evert and others, the problem was definitely related to outliers.  I was able to obtain a much better fit after removing outliers.  Looking at my old code, it seems I computed the median absolute deviation for each aspect, then removed anything outside of 2*mad before fitting.

I generated a few additional plots back in November 2012:

[image: histogram]

[image]

But looking at these again, I'm almost positive they were generated for different input data.  It's all that I can find right now, so I'm including them here as an example of a case with biased sampling.  This method for DEM alignment is bound to fail for cases like these - and it has nothing to do with scipy's curve fitting abilities.

I ended up developing a different approach for alignment involving normalized cross-correlation,  sub-pixel refinement, and vertical offset removal for two masked 2D numpy arrays.  It is faster and consistently provides better results.  Although even that approach has been superseded by an Iterative Closest Point (ICP) tool (pc_align) developed by Oleg Alexandrov as part of the [NASA Ames Stereo Pipeline](http://ti.arc.nasa.gov/tech/asr/intelligent-robotics/ngt/stereo/).

Thanks for all of your responses and I apologize for abandoning this question.

Comment: *Nonlinear fitting is not magic*... give it a good initial guess espeacially on the phase shift, there are other things to try. Also check full output of the curve fit... it might be reaching max evals, etc. Though maybe there is a bit more, seems a little odd that the `c` parameter would not be more reasonable.

Comment: Is this question still an issue? I don't have a direct answer to your problem, but it does appear that your actual data are non-Gaussian. In fact, how far do the y-value extend into negative values? Even with so many points, a bunch of outliers can throw your fit horrendously off. Further, you may try and use `leastsq` instead, which also returns a dictionary with some information about the fitting evaluation (as suggested by seberg, but `curve_fit` lacks this extra information, according to the docs).

Comment: You should look at robust regression methods, e.g. m estimators or some sort of ransac.

Comment: I vote with Evert.
To give a better idea of what's going I would try binning the data into bins over the "aspect" direction, and then I would draw some box-whisker or violin plots. Either that or a 2-d histogram. scatter plots hide a lot of information and the bottom of the distribution is not visible.

Comment: +1 for Evert's comment. You could also bin points along the x axis, and then in each bin discard points whose y value is more than k standard deviations from the mean (as long as that's a valid way of handling outliers in your dataset).

Comment: Huge -1 for my failure to follow up on all of these excellent responses.  Just logged in for a separate question, and decided I should provide some closure here.

Comment: @David, you can actually add your own answer to this question if you want, even though it's your own question.  Then you can accept your answer as the 'best' answer, and it'll be marked as answered that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to get a sine wave with phase offset, you don't need a non-linear fit.

You can replace that `a * sin(x - b) + c` by `a * sin(x) + b * cos(x) + c`, because any sine with an offset can be written as an appropriate combination of a sine and a cosine("Phasor addition", like in a fourier transform).

If that gives the same result then it is not the "non-linear" fit that is the problem.